# Data Align Last Struct in Packed Struct of Structs

Tags: c, struct, iar

This is my second data alignment question today, but I think it's different to warrant it's own question. I'm working with some legacy code, and there are a few things that were done that are new to me:

I have a packed struct containing 4 structs and some bytes/words. I need the last struct, typedef'd BLOCK8_STRUCT (which is currently really only an 8-bit array) to be 4-byte aligned; don't care about the other structs. I never direcly refer to that particular struct in my code; I only access it by way of declaring the struct of structs (hope that makes sense).

Here's the declaration of the struct that I want 4-byte aligned:

```
typedef __packed struct
{
  u8 data[1024];
} BLOCK8_STRUCT;
```

Here's my struct of struct declaration:

```
typedef __packed struct
{
   BLOCK1_STRUCT blk1;
   #if NOV_BLK1_PADDING != 0
   u8 blk1_pad[NOV_BLK1_PADDING];
   #endif
   u32 blk1_rev_and_sum;

   BLOCK6_STRUCT blk6;
   #if NOV_BLK6_PADDING != 0
   u8 blk6_pad[NOV_BLK6_PADDING];
   #endif
   u32 blk6_rev_and_sum;

   BLOCK7_STRUCT blk7;
   u8 blk7_pad[NOV_BLK7_PADDING];
   u32 blk7_rev_and_sum;

   BLOCK8_STRUCT blk8;
   u32 blk8_rev_and_sum;

} PARAM_BLOCK_IMAGE_STRUCT;
```

I want to make sure that when I actually initilize an instance of the struct of structs, BLOCK8_STRUCT is 4-byte aligned. I know how to align data (IAR gives me a pragma to do so), but it's not clear to me WHERE I want to do this alignment. The compiler gives a warning when I try to do this in the declaration of the struct of structs OR when I try to do it in the declaration of BLOCK8_STRUCT.

Answer (score 0):

```
#pragma pack(4)
typedef struct
{
   BLOCK1_STRUCT blk1;
   #if NOV_BLK1_PADDING != 0
   u8 blk1_pad[NOV_BLK1_PADDING];
   #endif
   u32 blk1_rev_and_sum;

   BLOCK6_STRUCT blk6;
   #if NOV_BLK6_PADDING != 0
   u8 blk6_pad[NOV_BLK6_PADDING];
   #endif
   u32 blk6_rev_and_sum;

   BLOCK7_STRUCT blk7;
   u8 blk7_pad[NOV_BLK7_PADDING];
   u32 blk7_rev_and_sum;

   BLOCK8_STRUCT blk8;
   u32 blk8_rev_and_sum;

} PARAM_BLOCK_IMAGE_STRUCT;
#pragma pack()
```

Comment: Just to claify though: this will align to 4 bytes EACH member of this struct. THis may be OK, I'll have to think through the repercussions, but what if I ONLY want to 4-byte align the BLOCK8_STRUCT blk8?